# Error initializing callout mediator : The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available:

Tags: service, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using Callout mediator in wso2 for a proxy service named Sample Proxy. I have given the axis2.xml and axis client repository location too while creating a callout mediator.

While saving the proxy i am getting the following error

**Unable to add proxy service :: Error trying to add the proxy service to the ESB configuration : SampleProxy :: Error initializing callout mediator : The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing-Error trying to add the proxy service to the ESB configuration : SampleProxy :: Error initializing callout mediator : The system is attempting to engage a module that is not available: addressing**

Cany any one help me on this please

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to perform a blocking call via [Callout Mediator](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Callout+Mediator)? If so, you don't have to change any configuration in ESB.

Please refer the [Sample 430: Callout Mediator for Synchronous Service Invocation](https://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB481/Sample+430%3a+Callout+Mediator+for+Synchronous+Service+Invocation)